Prometheus Blackbox Exporter - maintenance mode
We run Blackbox exporter as synthetic monitoring solution for our apps.
However sometimes there simply is a need for maintenance that brings down the app and thus fails the probes.
In order to not have this influence our availability score, I'd like to put BB exporter into "maintenance mode" (=during which it stops probing), as possible in commercial solutions like BetterUptime or Pingdom.
How would I go about this? Just delete the probe during the maintenance window?
